# What is the for_each_sched_entity macro doing?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, scheduling

```
#define for_each_sched_rt_entity(rt_se) \
    for (; rt_se; rt_se = NULL)
```

I'm not familiar with what this for loop is actually doing. Would anyone be able to explain?

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.75/source/kernel/sched/rt.c#L621

Comment: `I'm not familiar with what this for loop is actually doing.` I do not understand, it's a basic for loop, there's nothing to it. Could you be more specific? What part is unclear to you? Note that you are looking on the implementation with RT_GROUP_SCHED __disabled__ .

Comment: It walks a structure of 1 element.  The alternate definition at line 516 walks up through multiple parent elements.

Comment: @stark Is it just walking through rt_se? rt_se has many pointers, like parent, child, back etc. Which one is it using?

Comment: The alternate definition of this macro uses parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This macro is setting rt_se to NULL after the instructions block that follows has been executed.
The use of such "access" macro is common in the kernel to make the code more clear and robust.

Comment: But what is traversing with? rt_se has many pointers defined, child, parent, back etc. Which one does it use?

Comment: It is just indicating the structure currently pointed by rt_se is going to be acceeded in the following instructions block then not acceeded anymore (rt_se set to NULL).
Using such a macro, similar to those that are traversing lists, make also the code more homogeneous (either you access one element or traverse a list, the code respects the same rules).